# Is Macie supported in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-macie

From the user guide, I don't see Macie in the list of supported CloudFormation resources. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html Does this mean that you cannot create Macie resources through CloudFormation templates?

Comment: I think you can set up EC2 with script to configure AWS Macie. I haven't tried it before so I might be wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Is it through boto3?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cloudformation supports only few functions of Macie.
At the moment (November 2021), Cloudformation only supports the following actions:

1. `AWS::Macie::CustomDataIdentifier` defines a custom data identifier
2. `AWS::Macie::FindingsFilter` defines a filter on the jobs' results
3. `AWS::Macie::Session` represents the Amazon Macie service and configuration settings for an account.

Cloudformation is still missing the core functionality of Macie which is the creation of jobs (based whether on a defined data identifier or a custom one). I hope it will be added soon to CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can configure Macie with CloudFormation according to the official docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Macie.html

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not supported. There's not much to configure with Macie, it just runs. Amazon explicitly states that Macie doesn't accept custom regexes, for example,  unlike Google DLP.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Macie can be configured using CloudFormation like it is explained in another answer